# Finalize queue stuck

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, windbg, finalizer

recently we have found out that one of our server application (so it's windows service) failed with OutOfMemory exception. We have tried to find out what's going on and we ended up with objects in finalize queue not beiing finalized so no garbage collection can occur on them. We tried to find out, which finalizer can cause this behavior by using Windbg but we can't find out which object exactly is causing it.

By using !finalizequeue command we can find out this:

```
    0:053> !finalizequeue
    PDB symbol for clr.dll not loaded
    SyncBlocks to be cleaned up: 0
    Free-Threaded Interfaces to be released: 0
    MTA Interfaces to be released: 0
    STA Interfaces to be released: 0
    ----------------------------------
    generation 0 has 28 finalizable objects (050eab4c->050eabbc)
    generation 1 has 15 finalizable objects (050eab10->050eab4c)
    generation 2 has 658 finalizable objects (050ea0c8->050eab10)
    Ready for finalization 3027 objects (050eabbc->050edb08)
    ...
```

3027 is incredibly high number (it's after few minutes of running, this number is still growing and never drops). I tried to find out, which object is on address 050eabbc, but it's always different type so I think it's not the cause.

If I tried to print native call stack of finalizer thread, I got this:

```
    0:053> ~2k
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll - 
    ChildEBP RetAddr  
    WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
    032ef09c 772f10b4 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\combase.dll - 
    032ef0b0 755ff0b5 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
    032ef0e4 7554b22a combase!NdrOleDllGetClassObject+0x1399
    032ef108 755ff10c combase!PropVariantCopy+0x177b
    032ef224 75511724 combase!NdrOleDllGetClassObject+0x13f0
    032ef27c 7558115d combase!DcomChannelSetHResult+0x17c7
    032ef2d8 755fd39a combase!CoRegisterSurrogateEx+0x3494
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RPCRT4.dll - 
    032ef2f4 76a9e4a0 combase!NdrExtStubInitialize+0x21a9
    032ef71c 755fc779 RPCRT4!NdrComplexArrayUnmarshall+0xcac
    032ef738 75510d77 combase!NdrExtStubInitialize+0x1588
    032ef748 755816d5 combase!DcomChannelSetHResult+0xe1a
    032ef7dc 75587aa5 combase!CoRegisterSurrogateEx+0x3a0c
    *** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll - 
    032ef82c 748ab680 combase!StringFromIID+0x28d
    032ef92c 748ab758 clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x259d
    032ef964 7487960d clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x2675
    032ef980 748ab55a clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x2162a
    032ef9dc 74878915 clr!PreBindAssemblyEx+0x2477
    032efa2c 7487887c clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x20932
    032efa44 7478a5e2 clr!GetMetaDataInternalInterfaceFromPublic+0x20899
    032efa8c 74777d71 clr!GetPrivateContextsPerfCounters+0x968
```

Finalizer thread is always stuck on ZwWaitForSingleObject so this is another clue that finalizer thread is stuck.

So my question is, how can I find out which object is causing finalizer queue stuck? Funny thing is that I don't use finalizers at all :-(

Comment: The quality of your stack trace is way too poor.  You'll need to setup your debugger to use the Microsoft Symbol server so these "Symbol file could not be found" messages disappear.

Comment: Something is using finalizers. Are you using third party libraries? If so I would start doing code reviews of those. Most likely the finalizer has crashed due to exceptions being thrown in a finalizer.

Comment: I tried to switch STAThread attribute to MTAThread attribute and it started to work again! Don't know why, because we don't use any COM at all.

Answer (score 5):

My "psychic debugging" guess is that some code that runs on an STA thread creates a COM object, but that STA thread doesn't follow COM rules re message pumping (and perhaps the thread is gone altogether). I'm only saying this because we see combase on the finalizer's call stack. Clearly, you need proper symbols and to look at both the native and managed call stacks:

`.symfix C:\localsymbolcache
.reload
~2s
kb
!clrstack`

Post back the results if you'd like to resurrect this question.

Comment: Similar cases here with more stack information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010449/determining-the-com-object-blocking-finalizer