# .NET causing private data memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-leaks

I am currently creating addins for a Zenon Runtime. They are written in C# and are then added to the runtime.

When I run the runtime without my addins, the RAM usage stays at around 30-100MB all the time. As soon as I add the addin, it will VERY slowly rise until the runtime starts hanging and becomes unresponsive with around 2 gig of memory used.

I am now trying to figure out if it's actually a memory leak on my side or if it's caused by the Zenon Application.

I already created dump files and a VMMap and also remotely debugged the addin. The results were:

Remote Debugging: Mem usage at around 5MB (maybe visual studio cannot really track memory of an addin which is inside another runtime?)

Dump file analyzed with `windbg`: Absolutely no memory used. Also at around 5-50MB max, unmanaged memory is up at 800MB.

VMMap: Heap at 75MB, Image at 300MB, Managed Heap at 60MB, Mapped File at 50MB but Private Data  up at 830MB

So my guess is: Private Data is the main reason why it fills up.

My question now: Can a .NET application cause the Private Data/unmanaged memory to fill up?

Anyways how I can make more detailed analysis?

Yea I know is a big question with not much to show, but maybe you can help me with what steps I could take to identify the issue... I am pretty clueless right now.

Comment: Use a memory profiler to find the objects that are stacking up. If you are registering events, make sure you un-register them.

Comment: Thanks! Wouldnt i see those objects in the dumpfile aswell? Is the Visualstudio diagnosis tool good enough for doing that?

Comment: I don't know how to read dump files but I would imagine yes, if you know what you are doing you would see it. The VS diagnostic tools may be sufficient, it lets you view the heap and take snapshots

Comment: Thanks. I am currently monitoring the memory with jetbrains mem tool. Right now it shows 9MB .NET used and 160MB total, i am taking snapshots every few hours to see the change...

Comment: Totally oblique comment here, but sometimes 3rd party libraries can be completely incorrigible. In those cases, you can wrap them in their own AppDomain and create/destroy that AppDomain as needed. GL!

Comment: Thanks! I will take that into consideration aswell! :)

Answer (score 2):

> Can a .net application cause the Private Data/unmanaged memory to fill up?

Yes, in several ways:

1. It is not unusual for a .net application to contain unmanaged parts. Often calling into C++ code for one reason or another.
2. It is possible to allocate native memory directly See [allochglobal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal?view=net-5.0)
3. Use resources that uses native memory. This includes some of the objects included in the framework.

> Any ways how i can make more detailed analysis?

If it is truly a native memory leak it can be quite difficult to find. It is however possible that managed object owning native memory is leaked. This would be most likely if you are not using any unmanaged code. The managed memory might be much smaller, so will not be as obvious. An example would be if you leak bitmap objects, these use unmanaged memory for the image data.

A good memory profiler should allow you to compare snapshots and show a list of newly allocated objects. The good profilers I know of are not free, but often include a trial period.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The part with calling into c++ code might be interesting... my process interacts with a library provided by the runtime and i do not know whats happening beyond that point, so maybe those calls are creating the leak. (Sadly that seems out of my hand)

I am currently recording snapshots, so hopefully i have more intel soon..
Thanks!

Comment: What i just found by comparing 2 snapshots of 2 different machines (one with low mem usage and one with high mem usage):
On the high mem usage snapshot, there are 3600 queued finalizable objects and only 90 of them are finalized.
On the low mem usage snapshot there is the same object, but almost 100% of them are already finalized.
I guess i might have found the issue (which is probably not on my end :( )

Comment: @Markus Friedl finalized objects may indicate a problem in itself. Ideally objects should be disposed, and disposing objects should suppress finalization. I view the finallizer as a safety net, i.e. nice to have, but not something that should be relied upon.

Comment: thanks for that information! So i generated some snapshots over the past few days. The .NET total/used was always at around 10MB while the total MB kept increasing over time. Looking at all the snapshots, it tells me that there are almost 6 million of 11 types of finalizable objects and currently 960 queued from 2 different types. I guess that can be the leak?

Comment: @Markus Friedl a large amount of objects on the finalizer queue is almost certainly a problem. It should be possible to use the debugger to check if the finalizer is blocked. See also [Com object blocking finalizer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010449/determining-the-com-object-blocking-finalizer)