# freachable queue keeps getting stacked, Memory leak

Tags: c#, windbg

We have a memory problem in our c# WPF application.
Since our latest release, the FReachable queue keeps stacking and memory get way too high.

Our application run a few EF linq queries ever few seconds in a infinite loop those get disposed without a problem. But when the application runs for hours, they did not get disposed properly and the freachable queue is stacked.

I have tried to use WinDBG to analyze the problem, but this is my first time with WinDBG.

```
0:000> !FinalizeQueue
SyncBlocks to be cleaned up: 0
Free-Threaded Interfaces to be released: 0
MTA Interfaces to be released: 0
STA Interfaces to be released: 0
----------------------------------
generation 0 has 138 finalizable objects (000001a9dca74378->000001a9dca747c8)
generation 1 has 46 finalizable objects (000001a9dca74208->000001a9dca74378)
generation 2 has 5177 finalizable objects (000001a9dca6a040->000001a9dca74208)
Ready for finalization 399109 objects (000001a9dca747c8->000001a9dcd7fff0)
Statistics for all finalizable objects (including all objects ready for finalization):
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
[...] cut away the low ones
00007ffeabfa33d0      248         7936 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeRegistryHandle
00007ffe932cde10      156         9984 System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
00007ffe932f3110       39        10920 System.Diagnostics.Process
00007ffeabfa1c98      369        11808 Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle
00007ffeabfa1080      496        11904 System.WeakReference
00007ffe932cd4f8      156        12480 System.Net.Security._SslStream
00007ffecf6b28c8      115        13800 System.Management.ManagementObject
00007ffe4ea9c0a0      578        18496 System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1+FinalizationHelper[[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1+ThreadLocalList[[System.Int32[], mscorlib]], System]]
00007ffeabf23b48      337        21568 System.Threading.ReaderWriterLock
00007ffeabf39028      817        26144 System.Security.Cryptography.SafeHashHandle
00007ffeabf94e30      940        30080 System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.SafeCertContextHandle
00007ffeabf13800      978        39120 System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueueThreadLocals
00007ffe522c35b0     1014        40560 System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1[[System.WeakReference, mscorlib]]
00007ffe932cbef8     1709        54688 System.Security.Cryptography.SafeCertContextHandle
00007ffed417c630      563        67560 System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController
00007ffe7a796c88      384       110592 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
00007ffeabf26a10     2130       204480 System.Threading.Thread
00007ffe5191f2e8     5988       239520 System.Threading.ThreadLocal`1[[System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag`1+ThreadLocalList[[Z.BulkOperations.AuditEntry, Z.EntityFramework.Extensions]], System]]
00007ffecfc9da48   234906      7516992 System.Transactions.SafeIUnknown
00007ffeabf41530   151161     10883592 System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicResolver
Total 404470 objects
```

There are a lot of threads in the dump most of them dead.

```
0:000> !threads
ThreadCount:      2139
UnstartedThread:  3
BackgroundThread: 69
PendingThread:    0
DeadThread:       2065
Hosted Runtime:   no
                                                                                                        Lock  
       ID OSID ThreadOBJ           State GC Mode     GC Alloc Context                  Domain           Count Apt Exception
   0    1 3d20 000001a99b9be160    26020 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     STA 
   2    2 36e8 000001a99b9e9440    2b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Finalizer) 
   3    3 34d4 000001a99ba5fef0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX    4    0 000001a99ba68eb0    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX    5 357c 000001a99ba70e00 80030220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX    6    0 000001a99ba34a40    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX    7    0 000001a9b4a0c1d0    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX    8    0 000001a9b4a1bba0    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX    9    0 000001a9b4a3bfc0    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   10    0 000001a9b4a39e20    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   11    0 000001a9b4a495a0    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   12    0 000001a9b4a5c430    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   13    0 000001a9b4a65150    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   14    0 000001a9b4a6e9a0    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   15    0 000001a9b4a807c0    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   16    0 000001a9b4a8b780    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   17    0 000001a9b4a88670    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   18    0 000001a9b4aa3e00    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   19    0 000001a9b4aa3630    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   20    0 000001a9b4aa0750    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   21 4dac 000001a9b4aa0f20 80030220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
   4   22 3218 000001a9b4aa16f0  1029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   23    0 000001a9b4aa1ec0  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
   5   24 3850 000001a9b4aa2690  102a220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   25    0 000001a9b4aa2e60  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   27    0 000001a9b60c54c0  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   28    0 000001a9b60c6c30  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
   9   29 3ff8 000001a9b60caab0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   30    0 000001a9b60c7400    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   31    0 000001a9b76f5bf0  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   32    0 000001a9b76f92a0  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   33    0 000001a9b76f2d10  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   34    0 000001a9b76f6b90  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   35    0 000001a9b76fa240  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   36    0 000001a9b76f34e0  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   37 2ddc 000001a9b76f4c50 80030220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  11   38 5ea8 000001a9bd0deb40  202b220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C99200:000001A9E3C9B150 000001a99b9b24c0 1     MTA 
  12   39 3b3c 000001a9bd0e0a80  1020220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  13   40 3bf0 000001a9bd0de370  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   41    0 000001a9bd0df310     1600 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   42    0 000001a9bd0dfae0  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX   43    0 000001a9b60c6460  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  14   44 379c 000001a9bd1362f0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  15   45  820 000001a9bd132c40  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  16   46 5e9c 000001a9bd1343b0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  17   47 2f28 000001a9bd135350  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  18   48 6514 000001a9bd12fd60  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  19   49 342c 000001a9bd130530  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  20   50 5be0 000001a9bd1314d0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  21   51 225c 000001a9bd12f590  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  22   52  560 000001a9bd130d00  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  23   53 55a4 000001a9bd131ca0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  24   54 5770 000001a9bd826e00  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  25   55 5670 000001a9bd82a4b0  202b220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C90C60:000001A9E3C91150 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  26   56 43f4 000001a9bd82c3f0  202b220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C983C0:000001A9E3C99150 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  27   57 1288 000001a9bd82cbc0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  28   58 580c 000001a9bd82b450  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  29   59 472c 000001a9bd8275d0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  30   60 4048 000001a9bd82d390  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  31   61 1d74 000001a9bd82ac80  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  32   62 355c 000001a9bd825e60  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  33   63 30f4 000001a9bd827da0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  34   64 5728 000001a9bd82bc20  202b220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C89928:000001A9E3C8B150 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  35   65 5ae0 000001a9bd7bfd30  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  36   66 387c 000001a9bd7c2440  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   68    0 000001a9bd7c2c10  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
[...]
XXXX   81    0 000001a9bdd20690  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   82    0 000001a9bde27a90  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
  37   83  aec 000001a9bde2d2f0  202b220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
  38   84 5970 000001a9bde2cb20  202b020 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   70    0 000001a9bde38920  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX   26    0 000001a9bde150a0     1400 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   85    0 000001a9bde14100    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA 
XXXX   86    0 000001a9bdd2d3d0     1400 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   87    0 000001a9bdd2e370    39820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
XXXX   88    0 000001a9bdd23710  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX   89    0 000001a9b60fd490  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX   90    0 000001a9bda93e80  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX   91    0 000001a9bde38150  1039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Worker) 
[...]
XXXX 1729    0 000001a9d85f3e80  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  63 1730 3894 000001a9c26da020  1029220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C65E98:000001A9E3C67150 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Worker) 
XXXX 1731    0 000001a9d8992780  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
[...]
XXXX 2131    0 000001a9dae84290  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX 2132    0 000001a9da97b6b0  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX 2133    0 000001a9eeb26ca0  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
XXXX 2135    0 000001a9dbf53300  8039820 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  65 2134  18c 000001a9eeb795b0  8029220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C3A260:000001A9E3C3B150 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  66 2136 6058 000001a9d9d93410  8029220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C296C8:000001A9E3C2B150 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  67 2137 61ac 000001a9db1ed440    21220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     Ukn 
  68 2138  a04 000001a9db1ea560  8029220 Preemptive  000001A9E3C5D8F8:000001A9E3C5F150 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port) 
  69 2139 4ff8 000001a9db2fc780  8029220 Preemptive  0000000000000000:0000000000000000 000001a99b9b24c0 0     MTA (Threadpool Completion Port)
```

The stack of the Finalize thread seems oke the me?

```
0:000> ~2kb
 # RetAddr               : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00007ffe`de420590     : 00000046`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000046`422fe040 000001a9`9ba19060 : ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14
01 00007ffe`dfda4777     : 00000000`00000100 00007ffe`00000000 000001a9`b49f78e0 00000000`ffffffff : KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0
02 00007ffe`dfda2ce6     : 000004a8`2d6b69da 000001a9`b49f78e0 000001a9`b4bd0960 000001a9`b49f7a30 : combase!MTAThreadWaitForCall+0x127 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\channelb.cxx @ 7234] 
03 00007ffe`dfdaa74e     : 000001a9`9ba138d0 000001a9`b49f78e0 00000046`422fe430 00000000`00001a78 : combase!MTAThreadDispatchCrossApartmentCall+0x1e6 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\chancont.cxx @ 229] 
04 (Inline Function)     : --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- : combase!CSyncClientCall::SwitchAptAndDispatchCall+0x697 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\channelb.cxx @ 5856] 
05 00007ffe`dfda8984     : 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`dff5c478 00000000`00000000 000001a9`b4bd0960 : combase!CSyncClientCall::SendReceive2+0x78e [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\channelb.cxx @ 5459] 
06 (Inline Function)     : --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- : combase!SyncClientCallRetryContext::SendReceiveWithRetry+0x25 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 1542] 
07 (Inline Function)     : --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- --------`-------- : combase!CSyncClientCall::SendReceiveInRetryContext+0x25 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 565] 
08 00007ffe`dfda9495     : 00000046`422fea30 000001a9`b4bd0960 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : combase!DefaultSendReceive+0x64 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\callctrl.cxx @ 523] 
09 00007ffe`dfda4614     : 000001a9`b4bc8c78 00000000`00000009 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : combase!CSyncClientCall::SendReceive+0x325 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\ctxchnl.cxx @ 726] 
0a 00007ffe`dfdd633e     : 00000046`422fed80 00000046`422ff320 00000000`00000000 00000046`422ff320 : combase!CClientChannel::SendReceive+0x84 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\ctxchnl.cxx @ 655] 
0b 00007ffe`e087c334     : 00000046`422fefb0 00000000`00000000 000001a9`b4bd0d40 00000046`422ff320 : combase!NdrExtpProxySendReceive+0x4e [onecore\com\combase\ndr\ndrole\proxy.cxx @ 2002] 
0c 00007ffe`dfdd0c28     : 00007ffe`dff83308 00000046`422ff350 000001a9`b4a7c310 00000046`422ff2f8 : rpcrt4!NdrpClientCall3+0x3a4
0d 00007ffe`dfe4fd72     : 00000000`00000002 000001a9`9ba138d0 000001a9`b49e0a50 00000046`422ff419 : combase!ObjectStublessClient+0x138 [onecore\com\combase\ndr\ndrole\amd64\stblsclt.cxx @ 369] 
0e 00007ffe`dfda29b8     : 000001a9`b4bc8c78 00000046`422ff3c0 00000000`00700000 00000000`00000002 : combase!ObjectStubless+0x42 [onecore\com\combase\ndr\ndrole\amd64\stubless.asm @ 176] 
0f 00007ffe`dfdccddf     : 000001a9`9ba04990 00000000`00f600ea 000001a9`9ba138d0 00007ffe`ad6a5618 : combase!CObjectContext::InternalContextCallback+0x1c8 [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\context.cxx @ 4328] 
10 00007ffe`adb27618     : 000001a9`9ba04978 00000046`422ff5c8 00000046`422ff558 000001a9`00000000 : combase!CObjectContext::ContextCallback+0x7f [onecore\com\combase\dcomrem\context.cxx @ 4225] 
11 00007ffe`adb2b9d3     : 000001a9`9ba62790 00000000`00000001 000001a9`9ba6c3b0 00007ffe`ad78bb90 : clr!CtxEntry::EnterContext+0x295
12 00007ffe`adb2e0d1     : 00000000`00000001 000001a9`9ba6c3b0 000001a9`9b9e9440 000001a9`9ba6c3b0 : clr!RCW::EnterContext+0x49
13 00007ffe`ada0696a     : 000001a9`9ba4e780 000001a9`9ba4e788 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!RCWCleanupList::ReleaseRCWListInCorrectCtx+0xdf
14 00007ffe`ad666bd5     : 000001a9`9ba4e788 00007ffe`ae05ff80 00000046`422ff870 00000000`00000000 : clr!RCWCleanupList::CleanupAllWrappers+0x39fd8a
15 00007ffe`ad78ea4a     : 00007ffe`ae05ff80 000001a9`9b9e9440 00000000`00000000 00000046`422ffac8 : clr!SyncBlockCache::CleanupSyncBlocks+0xc8
16 00007ffe`ad78e700     : 00007ffe`ad78e670 00007ffe`ad78e670 00000000`00000000 00000046`422ffac8 : clr!Thread::DoExtraWorkForFinalizer+0x17d
17 00007ffe`ad5c7d38     : 00000000`00000001 00007ffe`ad78e670 00000046`422ffbe0 00000000`00000000 : clr!FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadWorker+0x90
18 00007ffe`ad5c7ca3     : 00000046`422ffac8 00007ffe`ad5c5aa9 00000000`00000001 00007ffe`ad6991a3 : clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x40
19 00007ffe`ad5c7be2     : 00000046`422ffac8 00007ffe`ad70ecec 00000000`00000000 00000000`00989680 : clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
1a 00007ffe`ad70d676     : ffffffff`ffffffff 000001a9`9b9e9440 00000000`00000001 00000046`422ffbe0 : clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x4c
1b 00007ffe`ad5cb8b5     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00007ffe`ad70d560 : clr!FinalizerThread::FinalizerThreadStart+0x116
1c 00007ffe`e08e7614     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x8b
1d 00007ffe`e0b626a1     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
1e 00000000`00000000     : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

```
0:000> !ThreadState 2b220
    Legal to Join
    Background
    CLR Owns
    CoInitialized
    In Multi Threaded Apartment
    Fully initialized
```

Tried getting more info

```
0:000> !DumpObj /d 000001a9aad9d400
Name:        System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicResolver
MethodTable: 00007ffeabf41530
EEClass:     00007ffeac1aec20
Size:        72(0x48) bytes
File:        C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
00007ffead15c7b8  4001dcc        8 ...__ExceptionInfo[]  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_exceptions
00007ffeabf2aaa0  4001dcd       10        System.Byte[]  0 instance 0000000000000000 m_exceptionHeader
00007ffeabfa5d70  4001dce       18 ...mit.DynamicMethod  0 instance 000001a9aad9d028 m_method
00007ffeabf2aaa0  4001dcf       20        System.Byte[]  0 instance 000001a9aad9d448 m_code
00007ffeabf2aaa0  4001dd0       28        System.Byte[]  0 instance 000001a9aad9d480 m_localSignature
00007ffeabf285a0  4001dd1       38         System.Int32  1 instance                3 m_stackSize
00007ffeabf41470  4001dd2       30 ...Emit.DynamicScope  0 instance 000001a9aad9d2f0 m_scope
0:000> !gcroot 000001a9aad9d400
Found 0 unique roots (run '!GCRoot -all' to see all roots).
0:000> !gcroot -all 000001a9aad9d400
Found 0 roots.
```

Can someone help / guide me through this?

Comment: The finalizer thread is deadlocked.  Traditional problem, it is trying to release a COM object but the apartment that owns the single-threaded object is no longer responding.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which object or functions is doing the locking?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010449/determining-the-com-object-blocking-finalizer